# Desktop native apps using web technologies

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-platform, desktop-application

Are there any framework available that help to create cross platform desktop apps using web technologies ?
Couple of weeks back when I was surfing around tech blogs, I came across with framework doing the same and apparently Slack used it to create there desktop app from it. I am not able to find it again, I am not sure if it was TideSDK.

Comment: This is not the sort of question that tends to stay open very long on Stackoverflow - you should have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Having said that, electron - http://electron.atom.io - is a framework that tries to solve exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Got it. it http://electron.atom.io .It used by Microsoft, Facebook, Slack, and Docker for their application. Got the link from http://www.webappers.com/